# Inferring regression coefficient of two variables through a third

Tags: regression

I have 3 time series X, Y, Z

If the regression coefficient (slope) of X and Y is **a**, Y and Z is **b**, then what can I say about the regression coefficient of X and Z?

Comment: Why don't you write down the two regression specifications, substitute for $Y$ in the first using the second, and see how it unfolds?